# PDI CE _ Source Control

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I'm using PDI-CE 8.2 and do have around 20 Scripts performing transformations. I was looking for help on how to integrate with Source Control since Tools --> Repository is disabled? does PDI-CE 8.2 support source control?
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two different things

1. Repository option is disabled - pdi 8.2 is not a stable version, i would recommend you to use 8.3, pdi_8.3\system\karaf\caches go to this caches location delete everything and re-start the tool, you will see repository option
2. source code control - pentaho does not directly support version control however community has developed few plugins for the same.
   click on tools -> marketplace
   search bar type git, you will find 2 3 different plugin(spoongit,etc).